# Replacing flourescent with LED

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Any electrician's out there? I have taken down an old fluorescent and the light fixture and this is what I have found. Only thing wired was the white wire. There is a pink one in there that was just untapped and no wire not. The blacks were all nutted together and they have multiple grounds taped together. I have put screw nuts on all of them following my buddy Bubba Osborn to always be safe. Unsure what to do here. Usually can simply take a fixture undo white, black and ground. Chris Ewell calling out to you as well.

[image]

Comment: Can you get us a close-up of this mess?

Comment: It'll go easier next time if you take careful note of which wires were connected to the old fixture... Better yet take a picture before you unhook the old fixture.  I think your buddy Bubba's advice to cap everything makes it harder to tell.  This is a straight up modern switch loop, the last guy made it real easy for you.  It's an understatement to say *they don't always do that :)*

Comment: Also that business with several wires tied together under a clump of electrical tape, that is illegal unless they are soldered, and nobody solders in this day and age. I would undo all that, clip the bare parts of the wires back to 3/4” or so, and splice them with a wire nut.  This will result in pigtailing the neutral and ground to your light, which is fine.

Comment: Harper thank you, later today I will post a better picture, but at my keyboard making money writing code now.  Thanks for the info.  I just want it right and not eletricute myself or burn my house down.  I need to see in my garage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red wire should be the switch leg coming back from the switch.

The whites are all connect d so that appears to the neutral as it should be. Grounds are good. The two blacks should be one hot from the panel and one feeding the switch.

Take the switch apart and verify it is fed with a black and has the red on the other side of it. If so then connected your new light to the white and the red.

You should get a meter and verify your wiring if you are going to tpdo electrical work.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: Ok I am a software engineer and I am not an electrian.  Thank you so much for the response.  What type of meter do you recommend.  Multi-meter?

Comment: Ok so on the light switch check out the colors of the wires.  Correct?

Comment: Yes check the color of the wires on the light switch and yes a basic digital multimeter rated for at least 300 volts but better yet 600 volts. Amazon has them for less than $20.